# Слово "вот".

Tags: пунктуация

"Вот(,) она все ходит и ходит, подруги все давно замуж повыходили".
Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без контекста трудно понять роль слова "вот". Оно может относиться к предыдущему тексту как относительное его завершение, как подтверждение сказанному. Тогда появляется запятая после слова ВОТ на месте паузы.

Но, скорей всего, в Вашем случае это обычная частица, запятая не нужна. Вот справка об этом слове из ***словаря Ушакова***:

ВОТ
ВОТ, указательная частица.

1. Служит для указания на что-нибудь, находящееся или происходящее перед глазами или как бы перед глазами в данную минуту, на наличие чего-нибудь. Вот наш дом. «Вот бегает дворовый мальчик.» Пушкин. «Но вот толпа заколебалась.» Пушкин. Вот вам прекрасный пример.
2. В восклицаниях служит для такого указания на что-нибудь, которое сопровождается удивлением, иронией, насмешкой, досадой и т.п. «Вот странное уничиженье!» Грибоедов. «Вот дурень! Вот уж не думал, что так случится! - Вот невидаль: мышей! Мы лавливали и ершей!» Крылов.
3. Употребляется при переходе к чему-нибудь, что является следствием чего-нибудь предшествовавшего, выводом, заключением (в сочетании с союзом "и" и без него). Вот я и говорю ему. Вот и всё. «Вот он сделал так, как ему сказала, и… Садись чай пить, вот и разговор весь.» Л.Толстой.
4. Служит для указания на то, по поводу чего высказываются какие-нибудь мнения, что является поводом к речи. «- Вот попрекать мне станут, что без толку всегда журю! Не плачь: я дело говорю.» Грибоедов. Вот теперь вздумали квартиру менять, а разве на старой тесно?
5. Ставится рядом с тем словом, на которое падает логическое ударение, для большего его выделения (разг.). Денег вот дать не обещаю. Вот вас-то мне и надо. Написать - напишу, а вот поговорить - не знаю, успею ли.
6. В сочетании с последующими или предшествующими указательными мест.: тот, этот, такой, таков, и нареч.: там, туда, оттуда, тогда, так, усиливает их указательное значение (причем ударение падает на мест. или нареч., а вот произносится без : вот этот, этот вот, вот там и т.д.). «Прочтите-ка рассказ вот этот не спеша.» Д.Бедный.
7. В сочетании с последующими вопросительными местоим.: кто, что, какой, каков, чей и нареч.: как, где, куда, откуда, когда, почему, придает им смысл указания на что-н., находящееся перед глазами или непосредственно последующее или предшествующее (причем ударение падает на вот, а местоим. и нареч. произносятся без ударения). Вы вот что сделайте: помажьте рану иодом и забинтуйте. «Так вот где таилась погибель моя!» Пушкин. Ведь вот, какой плут!
   ❖ Вот тебе и на, вот тебе на, вот те на или вот так так! (разг.) - восклицание по поводу чего-нибудь неожиданного, не соответствующего ожиданиям, удивительного. Вот тебе и что (разг.) - о том, чего ожидали, но что не совершилось или превратилось не в то, чего ожидали. «Вот тебе, бабушка, и Юрьев день!» погов. Вот тебе! (разг.) - получай по заслугам (говорится при физическом наказании). Вот еще! - выражение отрицательного отношения к чему-нибудь. Вот как! Вот что! - выражение удивления: каково! не может быть! Вот-вот, нареч. (разг.) - еще немного и…, один момент и…, сию минуту. Так плохо держится, что вот-вот упадет. Подождите, он вот-вот приедет. Вот так (разг. фам. ирон.) - употр. в восклицаниях для выражения пренебрежения, отрицательной оценки. Вот так шофер! править не умеет! Вот так сыграл! (т.е. сыграл плохо).
   Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.